# How to specify interceptor at inject time

Tags: java, cdi, interceptor, jboss-weld

I have some beans for which, in specific injections, I want to add a given interceptor.

I was naïvely thinking there was something like a `@Interceptors` annotation that could allow me to write

```
private @Interceptors(Logging.class, Connection.class) @Inject MyBean instance;
```

Unfortunatly, [Weld documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.1-Final/en-US/html/interceptors.html) clearly states the opposite.

So, how could I inject an intercepted version of my bean ? Is it possible using a cdi Instance object ?

**EDIT**

Although LightGuard's answser is really relevant, it doesn't totally answser my question, so let me rephrase it.

I want to have an annotation that triggers some kind of method call event sending. For that, I created a CDI `Interceptor`, complete with its own interceptor binding (let's say interceptor is called `SenderInterceptor`, and the binding is called `SenderBinding`). What I want now is to add a CDI qualifier (let's call it `SenderQualifier`) that, when used for an injection, installs `SenderInterceptor`.

To be more clear, I want the following code to use `SenderInterceptor`

```
/* calling any method of that bean should trigger an event */
private @Inject @SenderQualifier MyBean aBean;
```

while this one doesn't

```
private @Inject MyBean aBean;
```

What I tried so far was

- detecting fields requiring those injections using reflections library (that works)
- create using seam solder an `AnnotatedType` from bean class (during the BeforeBeanDiscovery event) (the type is created, but not really distinguishable from the initial one) and giving that `AnnotatedType` the interceptor binding annotation.
- create using seam solder (again) a Bean from generated `AnnotatedType`, and giving it the required qualifier annotation

All seems to worrk, except it's the original bean which gets injected.

I could of course replace original one with intercepted one, but there are some cases where such interception is not required, so I have to keep both `AnnotatedType` refering the same concrete type. I was thinking I coulld do that in CDI, but it doesn't seems to work (as original type is never replaced by intercepted one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you would need to do:

1. Add the interceptor to beans.xml so it's activated
2. Create an extension to add the interceptor binding or the interceptor annotation to the type in [`ProcessAnnotatedType`](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.0-SP1/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/ProcessAnnotatedType.html) life cycle event. You'll need to call `getAnnotatedType`, add the annotation(s) then call `setAnnotatedType`. I strongly recommend looking at [Seam Solder](http://seamframework.org/Seam3/SolderHome) or [Apache DeltaSpike](http://wiki.apache.org/incubator/DeltaSpikeProposal) project for the `AnnotatedTypeBuilder` to make this easier.

Comment: First time I ever hear about those projects. +1 for that and for the way it could be added. However, I guess I should in fact add the types beside the existing one, instead of simply replacing them

Comment: In fact, in my case, `AnnotatedTypeBuilder` should be used in `BeforeBeanDiscovery` event handler method (as `ProcessAnnotatedType` doesn't allow type adding, but only type replacing).

Comment: Sorry, @LightGuard, but I have to mark your answer as non answering.

Comment: You could replace the type with the new annotation, that's what you want to do anyway. Adding a new type would give you an ambiguity exception.

Comment: Yes, but in that case I will only have access to the intercepted class, although I want to be able to use both types. I already thought about doing that, and have some code in interceptor to process or not injected instances, but it doesn't solve my problem. Let me edit my question a little further to clarify what I want to do.

Comment: Okay, now I understand better. No, what you want to do is not possible, you'd have to annotated the original type, or create a new annotated type based on the concrete type. You would of course need to add a qualifier to the type and the injection to make sure you are injecting the correct instance. A Stereotype would seem appropriate for that part.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, you could try `@Inject MyInterceptedBean instance;`, where the interceptors are listed with the MyInterceptedBean?

(Caveat: this does not *look right*, though, using inheritance for types that only differ in annotations ... probably acceptable when it's always the two stated *same* annotations and not different annotations in each case.)

Comment: Well, in my very case, I even can't use that, as some beans are remote ones acceded through an other CDI extension ([JNDIExtension discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8536437/15619))